# Autoplay not working on a Swiper corouser

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, carousel, swiper.js

I am building a charity website for an organization using a template I downloaded from Themeforest ([link here](https://preview.themeforest.net/item/perits-non-profit-charity-html-template/full_screen_preview/31831375?_ga=2.160057853.1143679341.1625494810-871874450.1625243250)). However, the swiper carousel doesn't slide.

These are the codes inside an `index.html` page.

```
   <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="micro-slider swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="slider-img" data-background="assets/img/slide1.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide-content">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h2 class="slide-heading">Grace Children Ministries</h2>
                <div class="slide-description">We’re determined to turn the lives of orphans and vulnerable children around.</div>
                <div class="slide-btn-box">
                  <a href="#" class="slide-btn">Read More</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="slider-img" data-background="assets/img/all.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide-content">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h2 class="slide-heading">Grace Children Ministries</h2>
                <div class="slide-description">We've been doing the same ever since 2005 and we're not about to quit.</div>
                <div class="slide-btn-box">
                  <a href="about.html#history" class="slide-btn">Our history</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="slider-img" data-background="assets/img/obed.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide-content">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h2 class="slide-heading">The Blessings Await You</h2>
                <div class="slide-description">You're always welcome to support us buy volunteering in the ministry, sponsoring kids or making a donation.</div>
                <div class="slide-btn-box">
                  <a href="events.html#" class="slide-btn">Get involved</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="slider-pagination">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
          <div class="ms-pagination"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- End slider  -->
```

Here's what I found in the `main.js` file.

```
var MicroSlider = new Swiper('.micro-slider', {
    pagination: {
        el: '.ms-pagination',
        clickable: true,
        parallax: true,
});
```

I've tried to add `autoplay: 2000,` but that changes nothing either.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As [documented in the Swiper Autoplay](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#autoplay) docs, use it as Object:

```js
var MicroSlider = new Swiper('.micro-slider', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.ms-pagination',
    clickable: true,
    parallax: true,
  },
  autoplay: {
    delay: 4000,
    disableOnInteraction: true,
  },
});
```

PS:
If you import the Swiper modules separately:

```js
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay } from 'swiper';
// configure Swiper to use modules
Swiper.use([Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay]);
```